# Multiple documents or arrays within a single document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am using Mongoose to deal with images. Should I allow one document for every single image or place multiple images into a single document using arrays. I mean, which of these schemas is better —

```js
new mongoose.Schema({
  image: [{
    title: String,
    description: String,
    url: String,
  }],
});
```

or this —

```js
new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    url: String,
});
```

With first approach, we would be having only one document.

**Edit**: To provide a big picture — we have been using 3 collections (in addition to other collections meant for other things) — `landingPageGallery`, `subPageGallery` and `subPageGalleryArchived`. Each of these three collections store only one document and these documents have a single array storing URLs and other details of about images for landing page and subpages. `subPageGalleryArchived` stores images which were previously in `subPageGallery` but are now archived. These collections are used to render webpage. We have less than a dozen pages and each page is expected to have around a dozen image.

Comment: Hey there, are you sure you should make it yourself? it seems that GridFS is the best option for image, and there are plenty of examples in the internet.

Comment: The thing is we don't have to store many images -- maybe not more than a dozen. I do not know if we should use this given the scale.

Comment: Do you want to associate the images with something else? in that case, if you have small amount of images, the first option is fine.

Comment: In document we are storing URL of images, not the actual images. So maybe that makes the first option a bit more acceptable?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Do you want to have just one document to store all images, so they're not linked to any other entities like posts, users, right?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Images are linked to web page. Each web page can have around a dozen images.

Comment: For a web page, it does make sense. So it's more like `const WebPageSchema = new Schema({ content: String, images: [ImageSchema] })` something like this does make sense. If you have something associated to it and you don't have a lot of images, the first option could be preferable, because a web page is strongly linked to images. You will have to look up only a document, otherwise you will have to do 2 database calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I understood the use case incorrectly. Generally as for most questions, the answer is "it depends". You can refer to the following [guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-models/) for comparison.

How to design data schemas for MongoDB database depends largely on how you access it.

If you have an entity like a web page that always contains certain set of images. And you always need to load them together, the first approach is preferable, as you can query the database only once to get all the data you need.

If your images relate to many other documents, you will want to query the images based on the relationship or some condition, then the second option is more suitable.

If you don't want to associate the images with any other entities, the first option is feasible for small amount of images, otherwise, based on the fields you provide, I assume the first option is to have one document to store images indefinitely. This is not a good idea.

MongoDB has a 16MB document size [limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents) so one day you will might hit the limit if you store a lot of images.

Also many operations a document level. For a real use case you might want to apply filter, sort, group, update, delete operations on images. It's much easier to do that when they're stored as documents.

Comment: People compare documents in Mongoose to rows in a spreadsheet. Going by that analogy, isn't the first option, in some sense, comparable to storing the content of an entire spreadsheet into a single row?

Comment: Not really, it's not really comparable. If you want to compare the data shape, it's more like the document **fields** are the **columns** and a **documents** are the **rows**. In your case, you are putting images into one `image` **field**, which means you try to put everything in a **cell**

Comment: Then it means that the first approach is even worse than I thought it might be.